# Post approval for crowdsourced editing of features in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, crowdsourcing

I'm currently working on a project that involves crowdsourced data collection using ArcGIS Online (Organization version). The only problem I have with ArcGIS Online editing is that when you make a map public, I can't seem to find a way to "safeguard" the edits - any point someone adds to the map (Malicious or good) is there unless I go and manually remove it. Because it is crowd sourced, the general public will most likely not want to install a special app or really do any other work than clicking a link and adding data.

Is there a way to enable post approval? If not, is there a way to sort the points in the attribute table by date created, and then I could check weekly to see what points are added, and remove any bad ones that occurred through the week? I also have ArcGIS 10.2 with advanced license if that matters at all.

Comment: In AGOL create a filter on your date, specify between option, and do your clean-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you posted this a while ago, but for anyone else viewing this post, this was my solution. Some data for us didn't necessarily need cleaned up. However, we verified the location of each Crowdsourced item (in this case, AED locations in businesses).

I created an attribute field called "Verified" and the default value was NO. Then I symbolized features based on this where NO was red. Once I was able to enter the map internally and verify locations of crowdsourced data,I changed the Verified attribute value to YES and they were symbolized in green. Basically, I knew that Red features needed me to take a look and green features were already vetted.

Answer (score 0):

I was way overthinking this - Simply sort the attribute table by FID to see the most recently added points and clean up the data.